# Image not loading in an Image Control

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have two Windows Phone projects. Both have the **same code** for populating images fetched from an URL, which is this:

```
<Image x:Name="imgThumb" Margin="0,-94,0,6" Width="90" Height="90"  Source="{Binding Thumb}"/>
```

And my code is like this:

```
string thumb = i["thumbnail"].ToString(); //fetch thumbnail from json object
if (thumb == "")
   item.Thumb = "\images\noimage.jpg";
else 
   item.Thumb = thumb;
```

On both projects, when json returns an URL Image, the picture shows with no problem. However, the issue is when **the json don't have the URL**. When this occurs I need to show the *noimage.jpg* image file. In the first project, that "offline" image shows, but in the second project, it displays a **blank image**. I've already tested it, and the source of the Image control is set correctly...But the Image can't display.

Some things to consider: The image is placed in both projects in the correct path and they are set to Content.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I know that "if (thumb == "")" is a lil bit strange, but I've already changed it to "if(thumb.IsNullOrEmpty())" instead.

Comment: By saying "tested it", do you mean debugged?

Comment: Yeah thats it! The Source property is set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it isn't correct slash for the source "\". Try to use other one "/" =)

Second. It's not necessary, but to reduce a little code, try to use this Source of the image:

```
Source="{Binding Thumb, TargetNullValue=/images/noimage.jpg}"
```

So you can change this code

```
if (thumb.IsNullOrEmpty())
   item.Thumb = "\images\noimage.jpg";
else 
   item.Thumb = thumb;
```

to this

```
if (!thumb.IsNullOrEmpty())
   item.Thumb = thumb;
```

Comment: About the backslash, actually I use '/'. I didn't use CTRL+C so I re-wrote the code here.

Comment: Interesting. Well, it's strange. Ok, but what about second recommendation? If it's not working, so there's so there is something wrong with the path or with the image. Try just to create image in any place.

And you sure, that thumb is really empty, may be there some spaces? I often use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(thumb).

Comment: It didn't work though. I re-checked for the 100th time and the file is there, I cleaned/rebuilded he solution, reinstalled the app, it still won't work. But on the other way, I did your corrections on the other project and it worked like before. Thanks for the TargetNullValue property, I didn't know that one!

Comment: I just copied my code and put it on a test project and it worked like a charm. Would it be some issue on the solution itself...?